# htaccess mod_rewrite for different url based on dynamic id

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

hi everyone i have a problem in url customization i have 2 type of url

first is

`http://domain/index.php?slug=pagename`

i want it as `http://domain/pagename`

2nd is

`http://domain/index.php?slug=pagename&id=id`
i want it as
`http://domain/pagename/id`

my htaccess is

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$

RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ index.php?slug=$1 

IndexIgnore *
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?slug=([^&]+)&id=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?slug=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [NC,L,R
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?slug=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?slug=$1&id=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: thanks **Starkeen** but my problem is stil same i use the code you provide but it not working  it show white screen whit some text of site plz help